# DBCC sqlperf(waitstats) contains signal wait time longer than last time waitstats was cleared

Tags: sql-server-2000, performance, performance-tuning

I'm trying to troubleshoot some performance problems on our SQL2000 production server.
I ran DBCC SQLPERF(waitstats) and noticed the stats hasn't been cleared in a long time.  So I cleared them and did some refreshing and noticed after only a few minutes, OLEDB reported a signal wait time in the order of hundreds of millions of milliseconds.  How is this possible?

Comment: Time to Get rid of SQL Server 2000 as it is an **unsupported** version.

Answer (score 1):

The signal wait time is aggregated across all cores. Any system with more than one core can have total signal waits longer than the last time you clear the wait stats.